# How would I go about storing this Array in the Chrome Storage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension

I've got this array that I want to store using `chrome.storage.sync.set`.

```
var SavedItem = {items: [
    {Keyword: "a", Size: "b", Category: "c"},
    {Keyword: "1", Size: "2", Category: "3"}
]}
```

I know the code above works when I use a `console.log` and check the results, but I want to save it using `chrome.storage.sync.set`

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({
      {items: [
        {Keyword: "a", Size: "b", Category: "c"},
        {Keyword: "1", Size: "2", Category: "3"}
    ]}   }, function() {})
```

I know the code above won't work, but I have no idea how to alternate it to get it to work. I want to use these variables(Keyword, Size etc) later on when I retrieve the data using `chrome.storage.sync.get`.